# CSS defined buttons collide on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have defined two links and made them look like buttons using css styling.

HTML code looks like this:

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><strong>Continue to&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>&nbsp;<a class="btn-white" href="/?page_id=137531"><strong>Accessories</strong></a> <a class="btn-red" href=""><strong>BUY</strong></a></h2>
```

How it should look

[image]

But on mobile devices, these two buttons collide.

Wrong mobile device look

[image]

Is it possible to style them using css, to display correctly, without collision?

btn-red class example is here:

```
.btn-red {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 500;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        padding: 8px 40px;
        line-height: 1.7em;
        background: transparent;
        border: 2px solid;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        position: relative;}
a.btn-red {
    background-color: #dd0000; /* change background color here */
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        color: #fff!important; /* change font color here */
    font-weight: bold;}
a.btn-red:hover {
    background: #dd0000; /* change background color on hover here */
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        padding: 8px 54px 8px 40px !important;}
a.btn-red:after {
    font-family: 'ETmodules';
        font-size: 32px;
        opacity: 0;
        speak: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        font-size: 32px;
        line-height: 1em;
        content: "\35";
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: -1em;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
        transition: all 0.2s;}
a.btn-red:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
    display: block!important;
        font-family: 'ETmodules';
        speak: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        right: 0px;
        top: 5px;
    margin-left: 0;}
```

EDIT:
I tried to use responsiveness for padding, which should be enough to solve my issue, but its not working as intended. What exactly is wrong? Code is included in btn-red class.

code here:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1024px){ padding: 8px 40px;}
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 320px) {padding: 2px 10px;}
```

Comment: Use media queries to responsiveness.

Comment: This looks like a simple issue of not enough space available, so naturally those elements break into the “next line” at some point. _“Is it possible to style them using css, to display correctly, without collision?”_ - make them smaller, or provide more space …?

Comment: Refer this for media queries https://stackoverflow.com/a/35605310/5383669

Comment: media queries is the answer but need bit more help

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work. However, I am not sure.

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><strong>Continue to&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>&nbsp;<a class="btn-white" href="/?page_id=137531"><strong>Accessories</strong></a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class="btn-red" href=""><strong>BUY</strong></a></h2>
```

I had just added   six times.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this ...

Place "Continue to" & the buttons in two separate div elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="display-ib">Continue to</div>
<div class="display-ib">
    <button class="btn1"></button>
    <button class="btn2"></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.display-ib {
    display: block;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .display-ib {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Being mobile first as per the trend today